# Why is unchecking emitter not removing text?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, particles

I am trying [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q93pE5jB1Uw) tutorial where I wan to dissolve text. At 30 frame I added key-frame and 31 frame I removed emitter checkbox. I replayed the all keyframe and found that the text does not disappear. How to make the original text disappear?

[image]

Blendfile: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=46274

Comment: Checkbox properties are not animatable that way, you can't keyframe checkboxes.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I just want to remove text after all particle appears. I can see that if I right click on checkbox I can see insert keyframe

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos You absolutely can. Not all of them are animatable, but most (including *show emitter*) are.

Comment: @gandalf3 Didn't know that, always thought those were not possible to animate that way. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That setting only applies in the render. If you turn on rendered shading (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) the text should vanish on cue.